# Remove Reported Metrics of Istio Sidecar

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar, istio-prometheus

I use Istio 1.8 for service mesh and Prometheus to collect metrics from sidecards. Currently these metrics are been provided by sidecards:

```
istio_request_bytes_bucket  
istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket  
istio_requests_total    
envoy_cluster_upstream_cx_connect_ms_bucket 
istio_request_messages_total    
istio_response_messages_total   
envoy_cluster_upstream_cx_length_ms_bucket  
istio_response_bytes_bucket 
istio_request_bytes_sum 
istio_request_bytes_count
```

This amount of metrics use lots of network bandwidth. (We have around 5k pods)

All we need for now are `istio_requests_total` and `istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket` only from **Inbound**.
I know how to remove labels by `EnvoyFilter` but I was unable to find documentation for removing a metric.

Comment: According to the [Istio docs](https://istio.io/v1.8/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/customize-metrics/) _The `metrics` section provides values for the metric dimensions as expressions, and allows you to remove or override the existing metric dimensions. You can modify the standard metric definitions using `tags_to_remove` or by re-defining a dimension. These configuration settings are also exposed as istioctl installation options, which allow you to customize different metrics for gateways and sidecars as well as for the inbound or outbound direction."_

Answer (score 1):

*For better visibility I'm posting my comment as a **Community Wiki** answer as it is only the extension of what [Peter Claes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11567589/peter-claes) already mentioned in his answer.*

According to the [Istio docs](https://istio.io/v1.8/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/customize-metrics/):

> The `metrics` section provides values for the metric dimensions as
> expressions, and allows you to remove or override the existing metric
> dimensions. You can modify the standard metric definitions using
> `tags_to_remove` or by re-defining a dimension. These configuration
> settings are also exposed as istioctl installation options, which
> allow you to customize different metrics for gateways and sidecars as
> well as for the inbound or outbound direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the info regarding customizing Istio (1.8) metrics :

https://istio.io/v1.8/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/customize-metrics/